# Mongoose method chain order doesn't seem to matter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was using mongoose to query my database when I noticed that the order of methods doesn't really seem to matter. Why is this?

```
find({}, { __v: 0, _id: 0 })
.skip(skip)
.limit(limit)
.sort("age")
```

how does the above query result in the same data as the following:

```
find({}, { __v: 0, _id: 0 })
.sort("age")
.skip(skip)
.limit(limit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mongoose [Model.find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find) initializes and returns a [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) object.  It does not send anything to the database server, and does not execute any data operation.

The query object has methods [sort](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-sort), [skip](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-skip), [limit](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-limit). Each of these will modify the query, and return the modified object.

The query is executed when the promise is awaited, or the [exec](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec) method is called.

Essentially, `find` and the query methods build a [find](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/find/#find) database command that is submitted to the mongodb server all at once.

Both of the sample snippets will produce the same database command to be sent:

```
{
  find: "collectionname",
  filter: {},
  sort: {"age": 1},
  projection: { __v: 0, _id: 0},
  skip: skip,
  limit: limit
}
```

The mongodb server will sort the results first, then skip, then limit.  If you need the processed in a different order, consider using [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/aggregate/)